# Bootstrap 4 and Javascript Function - Hide form after validation check

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I have a simple html page designed with Bootstrap 4. There are two small forms placed one below another. I have enabled bootstrap form validation in both the forms. I would like only the first form to be visible when the page first loads. The second one should stay hidden. Once the user clicks on the submit button on the first form, the first form should get hidden and the second form should be displayed. Following is the code for the forms:

```
<main role="main" class="container">
    <div class="container" id="emailDiv">

     <form action="#" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
       <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter registered email" name="email" required>
       <div class="valid-feedback">Entry validated!</div>
       <div class="invalid-feedback">Please fill out this mandatory field.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-check">
       <label class="form-check-label">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkterms" required> Terms &amp Conditions
        <div class="valid-feedback">You have accepted the terms &amp conditions.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Acceptance of the terms &amp conditions is mandatory.</div>
       </label>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="SendOTPButton" onclick="hideEmailForm()">Send OTP</button>
     </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container" id="otpDiv">
     <form action="#" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
       <div class="form-group mt-3">
        <label for="otp">Enter OTP:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="otp" placeholder="Enter the OTP which has been sent to your registered email address." name="otp">
        <div class="valid-feedback">OTP entered.</div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please enter the mandatory OTP.</div>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
     </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <script>
    // Disable form submissions if there are invalid fields.
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        // Get the forms we want to add validation styles to.
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        // Loop over them and prevent submission
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
          form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
              event.preventDefault();
              event.stopPropagation();
            }
            form.classList.add('was-validated');
          }, false);
        });
      }, false);
    })();
    </script>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("emailDiv").style.display="block";
      document.getElementById("otpDiv").style.display="none";
    </script>
    <script>
     function hideEmailForm() {
      document.getElementById("emailDiv").style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("otpDiv").style.display="block";
     }
    </script>
   </main>
```

I tried to hide the first form using a Javascript function enclosed in the `<script>` tags. The hide and show feature works as expected but the onclick event is over-riding the form validation of Bootstrap 4. The first form gets hidden without form validation and the second one gets displayed. I would like the first form to be validated first and then get hidden. If validation fails, the first form should not get hidden.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: 1. As a general rule, best avoid inline code. 2. Bootstrap has a class called `d-none` that is used to hide elements. 3. To react to validation and submission, expand the bootstrap example code that handles validation: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/gt1vyjru/

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable advice. It worked like a charm! Quick question though: The validation does not work for the second form (otp form). Ideally, this statement should work for both forms when all forms on the page are looped: ```if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }``` The validation works only on the first form. Any thought?

Comment: Do you have any requirements for input with id="otp" ?  Looks like not.  You probably need required or pattern with regex to have that validate.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I had totally missed it. A "required" tag was required for the otp form for the validation. Thanks for the help!! :-)